# How to make ref arrays work in Vue 3 composition API when passing them to child components?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have the following todo app with these two components: `App` and `Todo`

**App.vue**

```js
<template>
  <div class="todo-list">
    <div :key="index" v-for="(todo, index) in state.todos">
      <Todo :todo="todo" :state="state" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { reactive } from '@vue/composition-api';
import Todo from './components/Todo.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    Todo
  },
  setup() {
    let state = reactive({
      todos: [
        { text: 'Learn about Vue', isCompleted: false },
        { text: 'Meet friend for lunch', isCompleted: false },
        { text: 'Build really cool todo app', isCompleted: false }
      ]
    });

    return { state };
  }
};
</script>
```

**Todo.vue**

```js
<template>
  <div class="todo">{{ todo.text }}<button @click="deleteTodo">x</button></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['todo', 'state'],
  setup({ todo, state }) {
    const deleteTodo = () => {
      state.todos = state.todos.filter(t => t != todo);
    };

    return {
      deleteTodo
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

The `deleteTodo` function works fine in the **Todo.vue** component, however, I would like to know if it's possible not to pass a `state` object but rather use a `ref()` like so and pass the  `todos`...

So in **App.vue**

```js
//...
    let todos = ref({[
        { text: 'Learn about Vue', isCompleted: false },
        { text: 'Meet friend for lunch', isCompleted: false },
        { text: 'Build really cool todo app', isCompleted: false }
      ]);
//...
```

Instead of:

```js
//...
   let state = reactive({
      todos: [
        { text: 'Learn about Vue', isCompleted: false },
        { text: 'Meet friend for lunch', isCompleted: false },
        { text: 'Build really cool todo app', isCompleted: false }
      ]
    });
//...
```

However, when I try to do this... the child is unable to filter the deleted todo and re-assign to the `todos` variable. This doesn't work.

Any ideas how I can make it work with `ref`?

Comment: Mutating props directly is an anti-pattern. You should avoid doing this. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

Comment: That helped. Should have provided that as an answer. I would have accepted. Though with a bit more detail for the benefit of others. Specifically, I've used the emit event from child to handle changing state in the parent. Now I'm able to use `ref()` in parent.

Answer (score -1):

you are using ref in wrong way. `ref` means to be used with reactive primitive values like `numbers` and `string` etc. while `reactive` means to be used for reactive objects.

you can use arrays as well with ref. but you should not wrap arrays within an object to use inside `ref`

The correct statement would be

```js
let todos = ref([      
        { text: 'Learn about Vue', isCompleted: false },
        { text: 'Meet friend for lunch', isCompleted: false },
        { text: 'Build really cool todo app', isCompleted: false }
    ])
```

then you can filter as you were doing it. only now you have to refer arrays like `todos.value`. kind of you already doing `state` variable.

https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-fundamentals.html#declaring-reactive-state